# haskell function given type signature of boolean

Tags: haskell

If I have this type signature, what function should I write to satisfy it?

```
allPair :: [a -> b -> Bool] -> [(a,b)] -> Bool
```

The only thing I know is `==` has type `a -> a -> Bool`.

It returns True if all the functions applied to their corresponding pair values return True - otherwise False.
It also returns false if there are different numbers of functions and pairs.

Comment: There are too many possible things that that function could do. The name of the function alone is not enough; you should describe its behaviour.

Comment: It returns True if all the functions applied to their corresponding pair values return True - otherwise False.It also returns false if there are different numbers of functions and pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible implementations, but it seems like the one you are reaching for is a function that takes the first element of the `[a -> b -> Bool]` list and applies it to the values taken from the first element of the `[(a, b)]` list to produce a `Bool` which will be `&&`-ed together with the analogous outputs from the second elements, third elements, and so on.

Here is a function to do this, under the assumption that the base case of no data evaluates to `True`, and that whenever there are more functions than arg-pairs, or more arg-pairs than functions, it should be `False`.

```
allPair :: [a -> b -> Bool] -> [(a, b)] -> Bool
allPair [] [] = True
allPair _ [] = False
allPair [] _ = False
allPair (f:fs) ((a,b):vals) = (f a b) && (allPair fs vals)
```

for instance

```
Prelude> allPair [(>), (<)] [(3, 1), (10, 2)]
False
Prelude> allPair [(>), (<)] [(3, 1), (2, 10)]
True
```

Note that this function assumes the arguments passed to it will be of compatible lengths (or that getting `False` back when they aren't is acceptable). It is quite tricky and involves language extensions if you want to actually use the type system to enforce matching arity of `List` arguments.

Comment: That could also be written as `allPair fs = and . zipWith uncurry fs`.

Comment: Note that in that case, however, if the lists are of different lengths, `zipWith` will perform the zipping up to the length of the shortest. As a result, if you evaluate for example `allPair [(>), (<)] [(2, 1)]` you get `True`, whereas in my version (and apparently also the OP's desire based on a comment) it would evaluate to `False`.

Comment: I did mention that but lost it in an edit. It does subtly differ from the behavior of yours as you mentioned.